# Check whether people are online or offline in Whatapp - Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, whatsapp

I am trying to create a python-selenium project which checks whether the people in my whatsapp chat list are online or offline. Basically it bruteforces one by one to check whether someone is online or not and then it saves the data in a excel file. Also it gives a green background to the people who are online..

here is my code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.styles import PatternFill
import time

workbook = Workbook()
sheet = workbook.active

browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"F:\software\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe")
browser.get('https://web.whatsapp.com/')

print("Loading..\n")

for x in range(5,0,-1):
    print(x)
    time.sleep(1)

#the below function checks whether the 'online' element exists or not
#I got the class name by inspecting the WhatsappWeb page
def check_exists_by_xpath():
    try:
        browser.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@class="O90ur _3FXB1"]')
    except NoSuchElementException:
        return False
    return True


count = 1
#the xpath gets the name of the persons on my chatlist
for iterator in browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="_2wP_Y"]'):
    iterator.click()

    cellA = "A" + str(count)
    cellB = "B" + str(count)
    time.sleep(2)
    name = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="_3XrHh"]/span').text
    if check_exists_by_xpath() == True:
        sheet[cellA] = name
        sheet[cellB] = " isOnline\n"
        sheet[cellA].fill = PatternFill(start_color="a4d968", end_color="a4d968", fill_type = "solid")
        sheet[cellB].fill = PatternFill(start_color="a4d968", end_color="a4d968", fill_type = "solid")
    if check_exists_by_xpath() == False:
        sheet[cellA] = name
        sheet[cellB] = " isOffline\n"
    count = count + 1

workbook.save(filename="WhatsApp_Data.xlsx")
print("Complete..!")
browser.close()
```

But I can't understand, why the code stops after collecting data of 18 people? Also can anyone find a better technique to achieve this, other than bruteforcing..

Actually the code just clicks on the names of the people in WhatsappWeb list and if the element which display the online message (beneath the name) - exists then returns true or else false..

Comment: You can provide a minimum reproductible example to motivate other users help you find a solution. See : https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example